# Sending email using Spring boot java

Tags: spring-boot, jakarta-mail

I am trying to send email with java mail using spring mvc. I am also attempting to do it with java config and without xml configuration and attempting to use smtp and not gmail server. Please is there a good example or could someone provide an example. Every example i have come across uses xml configuration. Thanks for the help

Comment: If you are using spring boot you can use spring boot's starter email. I have blogged about it [here](http://kiranreddy.in/sending-email-with-java-spring-boot/)

Answer (score 1):

[SendGrid](https://sendgrid.com/) have a really nice Java library for this and they have a free plan where you can send 12k emails per month for free. Just sign up with them, generate your API key and then...

Put the following in your pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sendgrid</groupId>
    <artifactId>sendgrid-java</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.2</version>
</dependency>
```

And the following Java code is all you need to be able to send an email:

```
SendGrid sendgrid = new SendGrid("YOUR_API_KEY_HERE");
SendGrid.Email welcomeMail = new SendGrid.Email();
welcomeMail.addTo(emailAddress);
welcomeMail.addToName("User-san");
welcomeMail.setFrom("welcome@example.com");
welcomeMail.setSubject("Welcome to Example!");
welcomeMail.setText("Thank you for your interest in Example.com! It is still in Beta at the moment but there are a number of exciting features planned. Tell us what you'd like to see.");

try {
    SendGrid.Response response = sendgrid.send(welcomeMail);
    System.out.println(response.getMessage());
} catch (SendGridException sge) {
    sge.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: is emails sent via WEB API in this case? I dont see any SMTP configuration.

Comment: Yes it is using the SendGrid API so it will be go8mg through their SMTP servers.